# How to dock the speedbar in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar

Is there a way to dock the speedbar in Emacs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 39):

You could try SrSpeedbar: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SrSpeedbar

Comment: Thanks for that. Exactly what I wanted

Comment: I have a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005297/emacs-sr-speedbar-ubuntu-same-window. On Ubuntu cannot activate sr-speedbar.

Answer (score -3):

http://cedet.sourceforge.net/speedbar.shtml

[image: speedbar pic]

EmacsWiki: sr-speedbar.el -> http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/sr-speedbar.el

Speedbar Homepage -> http://cedet.sourceforge.net/speedbar.shtml

Comment: doesn't answer the questions, it's just a screenshot.

Comment: It answers the question: yes, there is a way.  It is not, however, helpful.