# emacs sr-speedbar ubuntu - same window

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emacs-speedbar

I am on ubuntu. Just installed sr-speebar via marmalade. I know speedbar comes built in but I was not able using the [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeedBar) directions to get it into the same frame.

So I installed via marmalde this package [speedar Maramalade](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/sr-speedbar)

I have put (require 'sr-speedbar) in my .emacs.

The issue is that on Ubuntu windows key opens a window mode. So I can't test it. there are a whole pile of comands but I can't get it too work.

```
`sr-speedbar-open' Open `sr-speedbar' window. `sr-speedbar-close' Close `sr-speedbar' window.
```

. 
How could I get this working?

Update:
set the keyboard shortcut

```
(require 'sr-speedbar)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'sr-speedbar-open)
```

However now I get this error

```
Symbol's function definition is void: sr-speedbar-open
```

Comment: As anything else in emacs?! `M-x CMD <RET>`, or bind it to a key of your choosing, e.g. `(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-r") 'sr-speedbar-toggle)`

Comment: Marmalade tag is for marmalade sdk

Comment: Actually found out that its the sr-speedbar version in marmalade repo that fails. Download from here http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/sr-speedbar.el and it works.